# How to take user Input in Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I just moved from Sublime text to Atom. I am using Java for source code and Script Package to run the code. I am unable to take input from User. Is there a possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Atom is generally a text editor. It does not support build and execution of code.

For taking user input you can try the [platformio-ide-terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) package.

Answer (score 0):

Install '[atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run)' if your code is for python.

And press <kbd>F5</kbd> to take input after you installed the package.